# Usage of scheduleDeferred in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Hi please tell me the usage of below code in GWT?

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {    
  @Override
  public void execute() {
    //code
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling?

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {    
  @Override
  public void execute() {
    // request data from server
    // update ui
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(this); // reschedule
  }
});
```

`scheduleFixedPeriod` better fits here, I know ;-)

Comment: Imagine you're creating a web chat application. You should request the latest messages from server periodically, like once per second. `scheduleFixedPeriod()` is one of the solutions here.

Comment: Hi loki, whatever code is written inside execute() method is executed exactly after sometime?

Comment: Right. For `scheduleFixedPeriod` you may define that time period. Check this: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html

Comment: Hi loki what is the input that scheduleFixedPeriod method takes? where to place that method in above code? Please help me?

Comment: scheduleDeferred is for something meant to be executed once (@loki2302, you’re right: not this but scheduleFixedPeriod is meant for the task you gave as an example)

Answer (score 17):

It defers some code until after the browser redraws the page (if needed) and pending events are processed (that is after the mouseup and click if this is done in mousedown)