# GWT DeckLayoutPanel sliding to a NEW (not-rendered-yet) widget? Doesn't work

Tags: gwt, animation, transition, slide

I can't seem to slide to a new, not-rendered-yet widget added to a DeckLayoutPanel, no matter what I try.

It appears without the slide transition if it's never been rendered before.

However, when I do showWidget(...) back and forward to the new widget, then the slide transition works fine.

Has anybody been able to slide to a not-rendered-yet widget in DeckLayoutPanel? If so how?

I need this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scheduleDeferred` comand. This will make sure that your slide command is executed, when the widget is actually shown.

> It defers some code until after the browser redraws the page (if needed) and pending events are processed (that is after the mouseup and click if this is done in mousedown)
>   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821963/usage-of-scheduledeferred-in-gwt)

[Docu](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred(com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand))

Usage:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {     
  @Override 
  public void execute() {        
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(/*Your silider comand*/); // reschedule 
  } 
});
```

Comment: This works like a charm! However is there no event after the new Widget's onLoad I can use? (Doing it in onLoad doesn't work - too early). With your solution which works great I have to do a deferred command within a deferred command within a deferred command (2-3 levels deep) to make it work nicely. Shame as it's a little bit of extra code and a bit mysterious. Thanks again!